# Can I add JLabels into an array?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, graphics, jlabel

I want to clean up my code and I was wondering if I could put these `JLabels` into an `ArrayList`.
This is going to be used for a `do-while` loop in which the collisions of my player will be checked.

Below is the `GamePane` class. This code has the moving player in it and has the code for the collisions. This is where I create the `ArrayList`:

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/**
 * This class Holds the game pane that has the moving player. It also contains
 * the GamePane
 * 
 * @author 602052004
 *
 */

public class GamePane extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {// *change GamePane to GamePane
    // This is were the game screen is made and the player is created.

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JLabel player = new JLabel();
    JLabel finish = new JLabel();

    // This is were the JLabels for the walls are created
    //JLabel wall1 = new JLabel();
    //ArrayList<JLabel> array = new ArrayList<>();

 ArrayList<JLabel> array = new ArrayList<>();
 array.add(wall1);
    JLabel wall1 = new JLabel();
    JLabel wall2 = new JLabel();
    JLabel wall3 = new JLabel();
    JLabel wall4 = new JLabel();
    JLabel wall5 = new JLabel();
    JLabel wall6 = new JLabel();
    JLabel wall7 = new JLabel();
    JLabel wall8 = new JLabel();
    JLabel wall9 = new JLabel();
    JLabel wall10 = new JLabel();
    JLabel wall11 = new JLabel();
    JLabel wall12 = new JLabel();
    JLabel wall13 = new JLabel();
    JLabel wall14 = new JLabel();
    JLabel wall15 = new JLabel();
    JLabel wall16 = new JLabel();
    JLabel wall17 = new JLabel();
    JLabel wall18 = new JLabel();
    JLabel wall19 = new JLabel();
    JLabel wall20 = new JLabel();
    JLabel wall21 = new JLabel();
    JLabel wall22 = new JLabel();
    JLabel wall23 = new JLabel();
    JLabel wall24 = new JLabel();
    int playerSpeed = 5;
    int FPS = 40;
    private final Set<Integer> keys = new HashSet<>();

    // The keys set holds the keys being pressed

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Open the GUI window
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Create a new object and
                // run its go() method
                new GamePane().go();
            }
        });
    }

    GamePane() {
        // Run the parent class constructor
        super();
        // Allow the panel to get focus
        setFocusable(true);
        // Don't let keys change the focus
    }

    /**
     * The frame that shows my game. It contains the game frame which holds my
     * JPanel GameStage and ButtonPane.
     */
    protected void go() {
        setLayout(new CardLayout());
        // Setup the window
        JFrame GameFrame = new JFrame();
        // Add this panel to the window
        GameFrame.setLayout(new CardLayout());
        GameFrame.add(this, "main");
        GameFrame.setContentPane(this);

        // Set's the window properties
        GameFrame.setTitle("main");
        GameFrame.setSize(800, 600);
        GameFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        GameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GameFrame.setVisible(true);
        GameFrame.add(new ButtonPane(GameFrame), "buttons");
        // Creates the new JPanel that will hold the game.
        JPanel gamestage = new JPanel();
        gamestage.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        GameFrame.add(gamestage, "game");
        gamestage.setLayout(null);
        // *Move the setup of the player and the timer under the walls
        // Get a sample of collisions going so that i can do it over the weekend
        // Setup the movable box
        player.setBounds(25, 25, 20, 20);
        player.setVisible(true);
        player.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        // Opaque makes the background visible
        player.setOpaque(true);

        // Setup the key listener
        addKeyListener(this);
        // Null layout allows moving objects!!!
        gamestage.add(player);
        // Set the timer
        Timer tm = new Timer(1000 / FPS, this);
        tm.start();

        wall1.setBounds(10, 15, 10, 480);
        wall1.setVisible(true);
        wall1.setBackground(Color.white);
        wall1.setOpaque(true);
        gamestage.add(wall1);

        wall2.setBounds(10, 10, 755, 10);
        wall2.setVisible(true);
        wall2.setBackground(Color.white);
        wall2.setOpaque(true);
        gamestage.add(wall2);
        // wall3.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        wall3.setBounds(10, 100, 100, 10);
        wall3.setVisible(true);
        wall3.setBackground(Color.white);
        wall3.setOpaque(true);
        gamestage.add(wall3);

        wall4.setBounds(100, 60, 10, 40);
        wall4.setVisible(true);
        wall4.setBackground(Color.white);
        wall4.setOpaque(true);
        gamestage.add(wall4);

        wall5.setBounds(70, 60, 35, 10);
        wall5.setVisible(true);
        wall5.setBackground(Color.white);
        wall5.setOpaque(true);
        gamestage.add(wall5);

        wall6.setBounds(60, 100, 10, 90);
        wall6.setVisible(true);
        wall6.setBackground(Color.white);
        wall6.setOpaque(true);
        gamestage.add(wall6);

        wall7.setBounds(10, 230, 60, 10);
        wall7.setVisible(true);
        wall7.setBackground(Color.white);
        wall7.setOpaque(true);
        gamestage.add(wall7);

        wall8.setBounds(60, 230, 10, 65);
        wall8.setVisible(true);
        wall8.setBackground(Color.white);
        wall8.setOpaque(true);
        gamestage.add(wall8);

        wall9.setBounds(60, 290, 125, 10);
        wall9.setVisible(true);
        wall9.setBackground(Color.white);
        wall9.setOpaque(true);
        gamestage.add(wall9);

        wall10.setBounds(175, 300, 10, 45);
        wall10.setVisible(true);
        wall10.setBackground(Color.white);
        wall10.setOpaque(true);
        gamestage.add(wall10);

        wall11.setBounds(130, 335, 45, 10);
        wall11.setVisible(true);
        wall11.setBackground(Color.white);
        wall11.setOpaque(true);
        gamestage.add(wall11);

        wall12.setBounds(10, 335, 70, 10);
        wall12.setVisible(true);
        wall12.setBackground(Color.white);
        wall12.setOpaque(true);
        gamestage.add(wall12);

        wall13.setBounds(10, 435, 60, 10);
        wall13.setVisible(true);
        wall13.setBackground(Color.white);
        wall13.setOpaque(true);
        gamestage.add(wall13);

        wall14.setBounds(10, 385, 230, 10);
        wall14.setVisible(true);
        wall14.setBackground(Color.white);
        wall14.setOpaque(true);
        gamestage.add(wall14);

        wall15.setBounds(60, 390, 10, 50);
        wall15.setVisible(true);
        wall15.setBackground(Color.white);
        wall15.setOpaque(true);
        gamestage.add(wall15);

        wall16.setBounds(230, 290, 10, 155);
        wall16.setVisible(true);
        wall16.setBackground(Color.white);
        wall16.setOpaque(true);
        gamestage.add(wall16);

        wall17.setBounds(10, 485, 750, 10);
        wall17.setVisible(true);
        wall17.setBackground(Color.white);
        wall17.setOpaque(true);
        gamestage.add(wall17);

        wall18.setBounds(70, 180, 60, 10);
        wall18.setVisible(true);
        wall18.setBackground(Color.white);
        wall18.setOpaque(true);
        gamestage.add(wall18);

        wall19.setBounds(120, 180, 10, 55);
        wall19.setVisible(true);
        wall19.setBackground(Color.white);
        wall19.setOpaque(true);
        gamestage.add(wall19);
    }

    public boolean areColliding(JLabel a, JLabel b) {
        return a.getBounds().intersects(b.getBounds());
    }

    /**
     * this method makes the player move. It takes the players speed and subtracts
     * or adds the player speed to the current position of the player. It also
     * figures out were the player is at currently aswell.
     * 
     * @param arg0
     */
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // Move up if W is pressed
        if (keys.contains(KeyEvent.VK_W)) {
            player.setLocation(player.getX(), player.getY() - playerSpeed);
        }
        // Move right if D is pressed
        if (keys.contains(KeyEvent.VK_D)) {
            player.setLocation(player.getX() + playerSpeed, player.getY());
        }
        // Move down if S is pressed
        if (keys.contains(KeyEvent.VK_S)) {
            player.setLocation(player.getX(), player.getY() + playerSpeed);
        }
        // Move left if A is pressed
        if (keys.contains(KeyEvent.VK_A)) {
            player.setLocation(player.getX() - playerSpeed, player.getY());
        }

            // Check for collisions
        if (areColliding(wall1, player)) {
            // Reposition the target
            int newX = (int) (25);
            int newY = (int) (25);
            player.setLocation(newX, newY);
        }else 

        // Check for collisions
                if (areColliding(wall2, player)) {
                    // Reposition the target
                    int newX = (int) (25);
                    int newY = (int) (25);
                    player.setLocation(newX, newY);
                }else
        // Check for collisions
        if (areColliding(wall3, player)) {
            // Reposition the target
            int newX = (int) (25);
            int newY = (int) (25);
            player.setLocation(newX, newY);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // Add the key to the list
        // of pressed keys
        if (!keys.contains(e.getKeyCode())) {
            keys.add(e.getKeyCode());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // Remove the key from the
        // list of pressed keys
        keys.remove((Integer) e.getKeyCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Below is the `ButtonPane` class. It controls the screen switching. The two screens that switch are the `GamePane` and the `ButtonPane`. The `GamePane` contains the walls and all the code to run the game. The `ButtonPane` class is as follows:

```
/**
 * This pane contains the button and sets up the button pane
 */
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ButtonPane extends JPanel {

    private JButton startBTN;// Calls the JButton
    JFrame game;

    public ButtonPane(JFrame g) {
        game = g;
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        setBackground(Color.gray);// Sets the menu stages color blue
        startBTN = new JButton("Start");// Creates a new button
        add(startBTN);// Adds the button on the startStage

        startBTN.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (game.getContentPane().getLayout() instanceof CardLayout) {
                    CardLayout layout = (CardLayout) getParent().getLayout();
                    layout.show(game.getContentPane(), "game");

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, try it....also, as I've already stated, `List` (and `ArrayList`) would be a better data structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could initialize an `ArrayList` with `JLabel`s in a for-loop like this:

```
ArrayList<JLabel> array = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0, i < numberOfLabels, i++)
{
    array.add(new JLabel());
}
```

To retrieve an element from the `ArrayList`, just use:

```
array.get(elementIndex);
```

If you want to put already created `JLabels` into an `ArrayList`, you can do:

```
array.add(labelObject);
```

for each `JLabel` object you want in the `ArrayList`.

Comment: But how would i take the already implemented JLabels and put them inside of the array list.

Comment: @david bautista Well, it would make more sense to keep track of the objects based on their array index. If you wanted to assign them to named objects, then you could assign an element from the array to a new object like: `JPanel wall = array.get(elementIndex);`. Also, I still don’t know if you are dealing with `JPanel` or `JLabel`.

Comment: i am dealing with a label

Comment: If you really want to assign the wall `JPanel`s you created, though, you could just do `array.add(panel);` for each object you want in the array.

Comment: if I use array.add(labelObject); and I put in array.add(wall1); it doesn't work

Comment: @david bautista What error does it give you?

Comment: - Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete 
  QualifiedName
 - Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete 
  MethodHeaderName

Comment: The following runs with no errors for me: `JLabel wall1 = new JLabel(); ArrayList<JLabel> array = new ArrayList<>(); array.add(wall1);`.

Comment: should i put in the code for my whole game because i dont know the issue

Comment: i posted the code

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ArrayList` to store your `JLabel`

But you will have struggle when add an already-exist `JLabel` to your arraylist (because, when you got it back you don't know which index to access).

The better way to keep track of your `JLabel` is to create a map, you often need to specify text for your `JLabel` so you can use it to identify your `JLabel`:

```
Map<String, JLabel> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put(your-label-name, new JLabel(your-label-name));
```

If you know your label is going to duplicated, then add prefix to your JLabel key.